# How to create stormpath user without password?

Tags: stormpath, express-stormpath

Some users of our application are admins. We want give them a capability to create new users. We think about the following flow:

1. Admin goes to "Users" page and clicks a "create a new user" button and fill new user's name and email address.
2. That new user retrieves an email with acknowledge that a user was created in our application.
3. The user clicks a link from email body and proceeds to "Set password" page and specify his password.

Is it possible to achieve such flow with angular + express? Is there any other possible flows which can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an invite-based flow, but you'll have to do some custom work with our libraries.

You'll need to work with the Stormpath Client and Stormpath Application directly, these are provided by the [Stormpath Node SDK](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/api/).  Inside of your Express middleware, retrieve the client with:

`var stormpathClient = req.app.get('stormpathClient')`

and the application with:

`` var stormpathApplication = req.app.get('stormpathApplication`) ``

On the application, use [stormpathApplication.createAccount()](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/api/application#createAccount) to create the user.  When you pass the new account data, set the password to something that is very long, random, and un-guessable.  If your Stormpath directory has email verification enabled, the user will get an invite email.  That email should link them into your Angular application, to a custom view which will read the email verification token from the URL and post it to a custom middleware on your server.  This middleware will need to use [stormpathClient.verifyAccountEmail()](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/api/tenant#verifyAccountEmail) to verify the token.

Then you can collect a new password for the user, and save it by setting `req.user.password='new password'`, then calling `req.user.save()`.

Hope this helps!  I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) and I am a maintainer of these libraries :)